# In Homebrew, how to check if a software package is installed and if not, install it

Tags: homebrew

I'd like to check programmatically if a software is installed via Homebrew, then install it only if it is NOT already installed. Here is the command I came up:

```
brew list gimp >/dev/null 2>&1 || brew install --cask gimp
```

But it does not seem to work properly. Any idea?

More specifically, I think this is going to work to programmatically install or update GIMP only when it's *necessary*:

```
brew list gimp >/dev/null 2>&1 || brew install --cask gimp
if [[ $(brew outdated | grep -c gimp) > 0 ]]; then
    for f in /Applications/GIMP-*.app; do
        [[ -e "$f" ]] && rm -rf "$f"
    done
    brew reinstall gimp
fi
```

It seems as if the name of the formula is taken to be `gimp >/dev/null` instead of `gimp`?

```
brew list -q gimp >/dev/null
Found a cask named "gimp" instead. Try
  brew uninstall --cask gimp

Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/gimp
```